# Jumbotron breaks navbar on mobile website

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap Jumbotrons go out of the container on my website which means the navbar on the mobile version does not fill the screen. Other pages where I don't have a jumbotron this problem does not occur.

I tried using a Card instead, but that has some problems when I put it anything other than text

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron col-lg-8 col-md-12"
        style='margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 15px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;'>
        <h1 class="display-3">
            <b>Welcome to SkyWars.fun</b>
        </h1>
        <p class="lead">We focus on updating regularly, and we listen close to
            our community suggestions.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>We have a perk system, comparable with kits or abillities. Any
            player can enable 3 perks at once. These perks give small advantages
            for your gameplay. Choose wisely, and adapt with your perks! Happy
            SkyWars! And have fun!</p>
        <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="../tips" role="button">Tips
                and tricks</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for the navbar

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../">IP: SkyWars.fun</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li
                class="nav-item <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') echo 'active' ?>"><a
                class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/" title="Go to the main page">Home </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item <?php if(isPage('/about/')) echo 'active' ?>"><a
                class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/about" title="Information about SkyWars.fun">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item <?php if(isPage('/tips/')) echo 'active' ?>"><a
                class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/tips" title="Tips and Tricks">Tips</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item <?php if(isPage('/donate/')) echo 'active' ?>"><a
                class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/donate" title="Donate">Donate</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item <?php if(isPage('/search/')) echo 'active' ?>"><a
                class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/search" title="Leaderboard">Leaderboard</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="../search" title="Lookup player">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="player"
                placeholder="Search player">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Images of the problem

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAYcnq6pPDmNlJsUUNBbkM1aFRITEQ5TUF4U0JxWXpOYVBV/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAYcnq6pPDmcnVsbTNMbkI2MnlNdmZocmtXV0FWbXpmUTdN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome.  Please create an [mcve] - and be sure to include any styles in addition to bootstrap 4....

Comment: @cale_b I am not really sure how to minimize the code without leaving anything out. I added pictures

Comment: The request is not to _minimize_ the problem, it is that you need to give us a _complete_ example.  Include the minimal code required to give a complete, runnable example.  Check out how to make a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: @cale_b the thing is that this problem does not occur on simulations.

Comment: Then how would you expect anyone to be able to troubleshoot it for you? If you can't reduce the code to a minimal reproducable example and share it with us, what about the code you have shared so far do you think will allow us to troubleshoot it?  It sounds like you think you need someone to look at your entire page / code, which isn't practical on SO.

Comment: @cale_b You're right. Sometimes I expect people to go far lentghs for me without anything in exchange. Sincere apology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.banner {
    background: #e9ecef;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.display-3 {
    font-size: 2rem !important;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary" role="navigation">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="../">IP: SkyWars.fun</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li
            class="nav-item <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') echo 'active' ?>"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/" title="Go to the main page">Home </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item <?php if(isPage('/about/')) echo 'active' ?>"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/about" title="Information about SkyWars.fun">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item <?php if(isPage('/tips/')) echo 'active' ?>"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/tips" title="Tips and Tricks">Tips</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item <?php if(isPage('/donate/')) echo 'active' ?>"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/donate" title="Donate">Donate</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item <?php if(isPage('/search/')) echo 'active' ?>"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.skywars.fun/search" title="Leaderboard">Leaderboard</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="../search" title="Lookup player">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="player"
            placeholder="Search player">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="banner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1 class="display-3">
                  <b>Welcome to SkyWars.fun</b>
                </h1>
                <p class="lead">We focus on updating regularly, and we listen close to
                  our community suggestions.
                </p>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <p>We have a perk system, comparable with kits or abillities. Any
                  player can enable 3 perks at once. These perks give small advantages
                  for your gameplay. Choose wisely, and adapt with your perks! Happy
                  SkyWars! And have fun!
                </p>
                <p class="lead">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="../tips" role="button">Tips
                  and tricks</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have reduced font-size for small devices, it was getting out of the container. Also use **.container > .row > .col-lg-12 [just for example]** before using the main class. For reference go through https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/ this link. Hope it'll solve your problem